# Handling data modification

Tags: php, mysql

I have such a situation. Here is my code =>

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['username'] . "</span></td>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['email'] . "</span></td>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['rights'] . "</span></td>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['last_seen'] . "</span></td>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'>" . $data['since'] . "</span></td>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'><select name='change_rights'><option value='sel'>* * *</option><option value='null'>0</option><option value='one'>1</option></select></span></td>";
                        echo "<td></td>";
                        echo "<td><span class='getinfo'><input type='submit' name='del_user' id='del_user' value='Delete'></span></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

Like you see , I've made preposition along of data **`<select>`** and **`delete Submit`**
this is all in one

```
<form name="" action="" method="post"></form>
```

Is it possible to make modification with `<select>` and also delete data from script like this and if it possible how? Or not can advice me how to that?

If I have html form like this =>

```
<form name="mod" action="default.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mod[]" id="mod1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mod[]" id="mod2">
        <input type="submit" name="ok" value="ok">
</form>
```

and php =>

```
if (isset($_POST['ok'])){
    if ($_POST['mod']=="mod1"){
        echo "one";
    } else {
        echo "two";
    }
}
```

(I've never user checkbox with php and I have not know it well)
something is not going well, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This does not look that good. Try using seperate forms for each entry and add a hidden field to it which holds the identifier. Another solution: add checkboxes to each entry and use a single form with only one submit button

Comment: If I'll make like you say with checkboxes, how I can detect which is checked, can u give me some advice too ?

Comment: Well.... use a common name for the checkboxes, like `delete[]` (don't forget the brackets!). Add something like `<input type = "checkbox" name = "delete[]" value = "$id">` to each entry. And have a look at the array `$_POST['delete']` afterwards ;)